# nServiceBus IOC interface

Tags: castle-windsor, nservicebus

Every sample that I've seen for nServiceBus has used concrete class for IOC property injection.  How do I register an interface? In the sample below, how do I register ISmtpClient to return SmtpClientProxy (a concrete class that I've created)?

```
public class EmailNotificationMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<EmailNotificationMessage>
{
        public ISmtpClient Smtp { get; set; }
        public void Handle(EmailNotificationMessage message)
        {
            //this.Smtp = new SmtpClient("localhost", 25);
            this.Smtp.SendAsync(message.FromAddress, message.ToAddress, message.Subject, message.Body, message.Id);
        }
    }
```

My configuration looks like this, but I don't see how to the concrete type (I don't want a Singleton)

```
Configure.With().CastleWindsorBuilder().JsonSerializer();

Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<ISmtpClient>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
```

Also, is there a way to get access to the actual container (Windsor in my case) to do any other registration stuff that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass nServiceBus the container to use and you can reference it after:

```
 _container = new WindsorContainer();

Configure.With().CastleWindsorBuilder(_container).JsonSerializer();

 _container.AddComponent<ISmtpClient, CustomSmtpClient>();
```